# jquery set div height loading content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a page with some buttons and by clicking them you load a different piece of code inside a div. There is the main div, that's called "pg", the child that's "contenuto" and the one that changes it's called "cont_in". Obviously each different "cont_in" has different size.
I'm already using a function as a callback of the jquery .load() method, but even in this way I always get different height just clicking many times on the same button.

here is the code in the click function handler:

```
$("#contenuto").load("legami.html", new_div_height() );
```

and here the function that should change the div dimensions:

```
            function new_div_height(){

            var pg_dim_new = $("#dummy_nav").height()+$("#footer_spacer").height()+$("#footer").height()+$("#cont_in").height();
            alert($("#cont_in").height());
            $("#contenuto").height( $("#cont_in").height() );
            $("#pg").height(pg_dim_new);            
        };
```

Can you help me figuring out what's wrong?

EDIT: I saw that the problem arises in the last two lines where I try to set the parameters as div height; if I comment them the value returned is ok (even if correct from the second click, but that's another story and it's easy to solve)

Comment: Please provide a code snippet or jsfiddle :) Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: `$("cont_in").height()` maybe it's because of lack of # in selector?

Comment: That's a typo for sure, but it's not that the problem, thanks

Comment: From the alert messages you can see that in some ways .height() method can't evaluate object property correctly; I don't know if it's a loading issue or something else...

Comment: remove brackets: `$("#contenuto").load("legami.html", new_div_height);`